# JQuery document ready strange array behavoir

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something wrong with an array, i'm using for jquery objects. When i'm using that array, array element 0 is showing, but the elemnt 1 is like no action. What could have made wrong? So way i'm using arrays:
**forms[0].show()** works perfectly!
**forms[1].show()** when it's alone - no reaction!

Problem zone is in JavaScript:

```js
function repClick(cid) {

 if (cid.charAt(0) == 'e') {
  cid = cid.substr(1);
        // this works
        forms[0].show();
        /* this works too
        forms[0].show();
        forms[1].show();
        */
        /* this does not work!!!
        forms[1].show();
        */
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 forms = [$('#addForm'), $('#editForm')];
 forms[0].hide();
 forms[1].hide();
});
```

```css
#section {
 float:left;
 width: 1073px;
 min-height: 600px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border:1px solid #C8C8C8;
}
.content {
 display:table;
 padding-top: 100px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: arial;
}

.cTitle {
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #C8C8C8;
}
.c {
 text-align: center;
 padding:20px;
 border:thin solid #C8C8C8;
 
}
table {
 width: 100%;
 border: solid black;
}
table th {
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 background:black;
 color: white;
 text-align: left;
}
table td {
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="cTitle">Items</div>
    <div class="c">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td>Thu, 24 Mar 2016 08:13:18</td>
            <td>Thu, 24 Mar 2016 08:13:18</td>
            <td>
              <button id="e4" onclick="repClick(this.id);">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td><button id="d4">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item2</td>
            <td>Wed, 23 Mar 2016 18:19:13</td>
            <td>Wed, 23 Mar 2016 18:19:13</td>
            <td>
              <button id="e3" onclick="repClick(this.id);">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td><button id="d3">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="add">
    <div class="cTitle">Add new item</div>
    <div class="c">
      <button id="addBtn">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="addForm" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cTitle">New entry</div>
    <div class="c">
      <div class="form">
        <form id="items" action="add_item.php" method="post">
          <p>Item Name:</p><p><input type="text" name="name"></p>
          <p>Some stuff:</p><p><input type="text" name="times" size="100"></p>
          <p>Some stuff 2:</p>
          <p><input type="text" name="types" size="100"></p>
          <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="rResponse"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="editForm" style="display: table;">
      <div class="cTitle">Edit entry ID:</div>
      <div class="c">
        <div class="form">
          <form id="rings" action="edit_item.php" method="post">
        <p>Item name:</p><p><input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>Some stuff 1:</p><p><input type="text" name="times" size="100"></p>
        <p>Some stuff 2:</p><p><input type="text" name="types" size="100"></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
     </form>
    </div>
        <div id="rResponse"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: dublicate ids? which ones?

Comment: Does it work now when you fixed the IDs?

Comment: Shomz, this code in JSFiddle does not work properly. Try yourself with different arrays/ array combinations;

Comment: i did not touch any ids ))) and they are different from beginning )))

Comment: Dude, we can see the edit history, lying won't get you far... Anyway, @Jamiec has the right solution for you.

Comment: you forgot to add a closing div tag for add form like @jamiec  said , check it.

Comment: yeah maybe i was editing anything about id, but 100% no dublicate but it does no matter, code fixed :)

Comment: i was translating stuffs from russian to english, but its ok thnx Shomz ))) hehe im so stupid with </div> ))) anyway im forward with work )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current HTML has the `editForm` nested inside the `addForm`. Therefore if `addForm` is visible, you can toggle `editForm` without a problem. However if `addForm` is hidden, no matter what you do to `editForm` it will always be hidden.

The solution is simply to fix your HTML.